# Batch : Use the FOR command to check the files in the folder

Tags: batch-file

I have made ​​a batch script to perform the following tasks : 
if the file `abc.laccdb` still in the `update` folder , show a message : `wait a minute...`. if `abc.laccdb` file is not in the 'update' folder , show a message : `updating data successfully.`.

My Batch script is :

```
@ECHO OFF
start update_data.vbs
:check
FOR %%F IN (update\abc.laccdb) DO (
echo wait a minute...
goto :check
)
echo updating data successfully
pause
```

with the script above , the message "wait a minute ... " continuously displayed in command prompt window, even though `abc.laccdb` file has not in the `Update` folder. properly if the `abc.laccdb` file is not there in the `Update` folder, the bacth application run the next line `(echo updating data successfully)`. please correct my script. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd)'s answer:

```
@ECHO OFF
    echo wait a minute...
    start update_data.vbs
    ping -n 5 localhost >nul 2>nul 
:check
    if exist "update\abc.laccdb" (
        ping -n 3 localhost >nul 2>nul 
        goto :check
    )
    echo updating data successfully
    pause
```

Display `echo wait a minute...` message in advance...

Answer (score 2):

A `for` command with a wildcard will enumerate the files matching the wildcard, but without a wildcard, it will not ensure that the file exists, so the code in the `do` clause will always be executed whether the file exists or not.

Use

```dos
@ECHO OFF
    start update_data.vbs

:check
    ping -n 3 localhost >nul 2>nul 
    if exist "update\abc.laccdb" (
        echo wait a minute...
        goto :check
    )
    echo updating data successfully
    pause
```

It is not always a good idea to have a waiting loop without some kind of wait. The `ping` has been included to generate a 2 seconds pause between loops to reduce the cpu usage.

Comment: thank you for your advice, but stay not work. the message "wait a minute ... " continuously displayed in command prompt window

Comment: @flyingbird013, as the paths to the folder/file are relative to the current active directory (not the batch folder), please ensure the folder/file if the check is the correct one. The `wait a minute...` will display for each loop until the flag file is deleted. If you don't want that repetition, move the `echo` before the `:check` label

Comment: good news .. after I changed the line `ping -n 3 localhost >nul 2>nul`  into `ping -n 6 localhost >nul 5>nul`  , my problem is solved. thankyou very much